# joining two linq queries to a single query

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following linq queries.. what is the best way to join both of them to a single query.

```
List<string> consumerids = plays.Where(w => w.playyear == group_period.year 
                                         && w.playmonth == group_period.month 
                                         && w.sixteentile == group_period.group)
                                .Select(c => c.consumerid)
                                .ToList();


int groupcount = plays.Where(w => w.playyear == period.playyear 
                               && w.playmonth == period.playmonth 
                               && w.sixteentile == group 
                               && consumerids.Any(x => x == w.consumerid))
                      .Count();
```

Please note that the two queries even though have a similar where clause use different values in them (eg. `group_period.year` and `period.playyear`)

Comment: why do you need them to be a single query? this will probably hurt readability. also, what should be the result of such query?

Comment: Why don't you just count `consumerids`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these 2 queries do different things, you can keep them separate. It is more readable that way.

What you can do to improve is make these two be executed as 1 query in the database.

All you need to do is remove the `ToList()`:

*You can also have the predicate of the second `Where` as the predicate of the `Count`*

```
var consumerids = plays.Where(w => w.playyear == group_period.year &&
                                   w.playmonth == group_period.month &&
                                   w.sixteentile == group_period.group)
                       .Select(c => c.consumerid);

int groupcount = plays.Count(w => w.playyear == period.playyear &&
                                  w.playmonth == period.playmonth &&
                                  w.sixteentile == group &&
                                  consumerids.Any(x => x == w.consumerid));
```